# como puedo importar una tabla de una base de datos a otra usando VBA en excel con SQL?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sqlite

tengo una base de datos en SQLite y una tabla en excel. Mi consulta es si puedo usar SELECT INTO dando referencia a la tabla de EXCEL para insertar sus datos en la tabla de SQLite. Quiero hacerlo de esa manera porque pasarlo linea por linea se demora mucho

Comment: De manera directa no, pero mira en Google cómo usar un archivo Excel como origen de datos, en el que poder pedir los datos mediante una sentencia SQL. Una vez que lo consigas, seguramente sí podrás hacer el INSERT INTO.

Comment: No he encontrado info al respecto. La alternativa que encontre es hacer un aplicativo en python con pandas (me ha costado hacerlo funcionar), convertirlo en exe y llamarlo desde vba en excel. Lo que no me deja conforme es que ejecuta el archivo pero en vba no espera que termine de hacer su trabajo para continuar con el script

Comment: @DanteT si el script de python si es capaz de esperar, yo lo que haría es que después de que cargue los datos, python cree un fichero .txt por ejemplo, y hacer que vba espere hasta que ese fichero aparezca para continuar. Es lo que hago yo cuando tengo que llamar a programas externos y esperar que éstos acaben su ejecución.

Comment: @Damian gracias, lo probare

Answer (score 0):

No es exactamente lo que buscaba pero indagando por internet encontre que con python se puede hacer mas rapido este proceso que usar solamente VBA.

Lo que hice es un script de python que luego convertí a ejecutable. Desde el excel ejecuto ese ejecutable mandandole como argumentos la ruta entera del excel de donde tomara los datos y la ruta completa de la base de datos SQLite.

En python se hace uso de las librerias "panda" para el manejo de los datos, "sqlite3" para conectarse a la base de datos sqlite3 y "sys" para tomar los argumentos cuando se ejecuta el ejecutable.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import sys

ruta_xls = sys.argv[1]
ruta_db = sys.argv[2]

#ingresar la ruta el excel con todo y archivo lo mismo con la BD
xls = pd.ExcelFile(ruta_xls)
db_conn = sqlite3.connect(ruta_db)

df=xls.parse('COMPROBANTES', parse_dates=True) # en este caso "COMPROBANTES" es el nombre de la hoja de excel
df.to_sql('COMPROBANTES', db_conn, if_exists='replace', index=False) # "COMPROBANTES" es el nombre de la tabla, no es necesario que tenga el mismo nombre que la hoja de excel


db_conn.commit()
db_conn.close()
```

para convertir este codigo a ejecutable se usa pyinstaller

Para el codigo de excel en si funcionaba pero algo que no me terminaba por gustar era que el codigo en VBA no esperaba a que termine el codigo en python. Pero finalmente encontre la solucion aqui .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902022/wait-for-shell-to-finish-then-format-cells-synchronously-execute-a-command

```
Sub RunPython()
    Dim exePath, ruta_xls, ruta_db As String
    Dim command As String
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    Dim errorCode As Long
    
    ruta_xls = """" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & """"
    ruta_db = """" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "mibasededatos.db" & """"
    exePath = """" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "exportar.exe" & """"
    
    command = exePath & " " & ruta_xls & " " & ruta_db
    
    errorCode = wsh.Run(command, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
    
    If errorCode = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Done! No error to report."
    Else
        MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
    End If


End Sub
```